# Как обратится к элементу ассоциативного массива по индексу, а не по ключу?

Tags: php

```
$MyArray = Array ( 'id' => 1, 'descr' => 'Молоко', 'price' => 15 );

// Так НЕ нужно
// echo $MyArray[ 'descr' ];

// Нужно вот так
echo $MyArray[ 1 ];
```

Comment: Нет, массивы специально ключом оснащены. Конечно, можно извратиться и выдать что-то вроде `$myArr[array_search(1, $myArr)];`, но лучше пересмотрите архитектуру тогда.

Comment: Откуда данные? Из базы можно с индексами зафетчить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сначала получить i-й ключ, а уже потом, по этому ключу получить сам элемент.

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```
$arr = [
    'id' => 1,
    'descr' => 'Молоко',
    'price' => 15,
];

echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[1]];
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://ideone.com/V8hIbW) на IDEOne.

**Замечание:**

По-хорошему, порядок элементов ассоциативного массива **не гарантирован** (хотя на практике он всегда соблюдается). Поэтому, с *ассоциативными массивами* предпочтительнее работать именно по ключам, а не полагаться на порядковый номер элемента. В тоже время, если для вас принципиален именно порядок элементов, вам стоит рассмотреть использование индексных массивов вместо ассоциативных.

Comment: Спасибо. Будем искать другой путь.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные берутся из базы, большинство драйверов поддерживают fetch с числовыми индексами.

На примере [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); 
// [0 => 1, 'id' => 1, 1 => 'Milk', 'desc' => 'Milk']
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
// [0 => 1, 1 => 'Milk']
```